# That-clause (content clause) as an adjunct?

Tags: dependent-clause, that, adjuncts

According to [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), that-clause can function as an adjunct.
The following sentence is an example from page 952 of CGEL.

> He appealed to us to bring his case to the attention of the
>   authorities that justice might be done.

But I can not find any explanation about that-clause as an adjunct.
What is the [semantic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)#Semantic_function) used in the above example sentence?

Any explanation and example about using that-clause as adjunct is also appreciated.

Comment: I can't offer anything particularly helpful, but I will say that as a British English speaker, I am perfectly comfortable with this usage but realise that it would not commonly be used in every day speech by the majority.

Comment: Think of it as meaning _so that justice might be done_ . It then becomes clear that it's a purpose adjunct. Content clauses as adjunct are not common; usually they are complement to a preposition like "so" (or a compound PP like "in order") cf. _Open the wine so/in order that it can breathe_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clause

> that justice might be done

is an adverbial adjunct modifying the verb *bring*, and giving the reason for or the expected result of the verb's action.  I.e., it answers the question why bring the action?